# install laravel octane roadrunner using docker

Tags: php, laravel, docker, roadrunner

I want to install and run laravel octane roadrunner using docker. Necessary environment that is needed to build docker container is setup like docker desktop, wsl 2 layer, php 8.

This is my Dockerfile:
[image]

this is my docker-compose.yml file :
[image]

this is my docker desktop log error:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I think you forgot to install and run roadrunner binary file in the docker container.

Add these two lines on top of your file.

```
FROM ghcr.io/roadrunner-server/roadrunner:latest AS roadrunner
COPY --from=roadrunner /usr/bin/rr /usr/local/bin/rr
```